# node js server post request ignores square brackets "[]" sent from axios what should I do?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, post

I have a form that sends source code to nodejs server. The problem is when I print the request on the server every character after `[` is ignored.

For example form source code contains:

`fib[0] = fib[1] = 1` is replaced with `fib` on the server.

request on client:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:3001/submit', encodeURIComponent(data))
    .then(response =>  {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
```

request on the server

```
module.exports.submit = (req, res) => {
    
  let x = Object.keys(req.body)[0];
  let decodedData = decodeURIComponent(x);
  let code = decodedData;
  console.log(code); // code is fib      
  res.send('ok');


}
```

Comment: Can you add an example of your data in post ?

Comment: @lamtacvu `fib[0] = fib[1] = 1`

Comment: The encodeURIComponent will escape the [ ] character. Instead, I think you should post your data with object, for example: `  data=  {fib: [0,1]}`

Comment: @lamtacvu Can you show me how please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send array value as POST request, you should use the object post data.

```
// server.js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static("./"));

app.post("/submit", (req, res) => { // POST is here.    
    console.log("your request body: ",req.body);
    console.log("your fib: ", req.body.fib);

    // lets send back to client what we received
    res.json(req.body.fib);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${3000}`);
});
```

And your client side can be like this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<script>
    data = {
        fib: [null, 0, 1, 2, null, 5]
    };
    axios.post('http://localhost:3000/submit', (data))
        .then(response =>  {
            console.log(  "server received fib data: " , response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })

</script>
```